# displaying selected json keys in django template

Tags: json, django, python-3.x, firebase

I have a django project. I also have a json ojbect that I want to pass to the template and display selected information from the object in the template itself.

Here is the object (user):

```
OrderedDict([  
   ('info',
   {  
      'bio':'brother of founder',
      'company':'MySplit',
      'dob':'1993-03-23',
      'first_name':'hani',
      'gender':'M',
      'last_name':'jandali',
      'phone':'+19515343666'
   }   ),
   ('location',
   {  
      'city':'Mission Viejo',
      'state':'CA',
      'street':'27806 Soller',
      'zip_code':92692
   }   ),
   ('status',
   {  
      'active':'1',
      'group':'dev',
      'premium':'1'
   }   )
])
```

This is the template that I have:

```
<p>
  {{ user_profile.location.street }}
</p>
```

Views.py file:

```
def user_home(request):
    if 'uid' not in request.session:
        # the following is for a user that is not logged in
        login = LoginForm()
        signup = SignupForm()
        parameters = {
            'login':login,
            'signup':signup,
        }
        return render(request, 'users/welcome.html', parameters)
    else:
        user_id = request.session['uid']
        user_profile = database.child('users').child(user_id).child('profile').get()
        print(user_profile.key())
        print(user_profile.val())
        parameters = {
            'user_profile':user_profile,
        }
        return render(request, 'users/user_home.html', parameters)
```

[image]

Comment: it isnt displaying what I want it to display @ne

Comment: so the json that you see is a print of the `print(user_profile.key()) print(user_profile.val())` @neverwalkaloner

Comment: OrderDict doesnt have `val()` method. Can you print(user_profile) and print(type(user_profile)) and check results?

Comment: i got the following `<pyrebase.pyrebase.PyreResponse object at 0x11154f320>` and `<class 'pyrebase.pyrebase.PyreResponse'>` @neverwalkaloner

Comment: Looks like you should pass to the context `user_profile.val()` not `user_profile` object itself. Try this: `parameters={'user_profile':user_profile.val(),}`.

Comment: I got it working. let me just make sure... Thank for the help